# How to set shell variable in ansible globally

Tags: ansible

I had a problem with locales on vagrant described in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277675/postgres-in-vagrantubuntu14-04).

For fixing this problem I need to set environment variable:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Is there a way to do that globally for playbook?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into this same problem with Postgres and Vagrant and Ansible. Here's how I solved it.

```
- name: dev locale
  action: command sudo update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
- name: set default locale
  sudo: yes
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/default/locale
    regexp="LC_ALL"
    line="LC_ALL=\"en_US.UTF-8\""
```

Yes, the `command sudo` line is weird. But it works.

Comment: i need to mention, that the [ansible module locale_gen](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/locale_gen_module.html) did not work for me (debian 8).

Comment: @michabbb make sure it is reported- [is this the problem](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/issues/823)?

Comment: my locales don´t have spaces, so i guess it's another problem.