# Vagrantfile. Set locale for ssh agent

Tags: ssh, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have a problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277675/postgres-in-vagrantubuntu14-04)

This problem appears because host machine put locale to guest via ssh.

What is the proper way to solve this?

How I can force vagrant ssh to do this:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 vagrant ssh
```

each time?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I propose override host locale in Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/vivid64"

  ENV['LC_ALL']="en_US.UTF-8"

end
```

The change is not visible outside Vagrant (host env variables remains unchanged)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are generally considered to be of low quality

Comment: I guess it works. but there is a question: Can the `ENV['LC_ALL']="en_US.UTF-8"` eventually change something on the host machine?

Comment: My host remains unchanged, so I think the change is local only (BTW, I simplified my answer a little)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on OSX (the solution is similar for Linux) when connecting to my Vagrant Ubuntu boxes.

I simply "solved" it by editing `/etc/ssh_config` (or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on Linux) and commenting the following line:

```
# SendEnv LANG LC_*
```

This basically stops `ssh` from sending the `LANG` and `LC_ALL` (all `LC_` variables) to the remote host, resulting in using the default on the box. In this case `en_US.UTF-8`.

Obviously this will cause your remote connections to always use the default locale which may not be what you want.

I believe that you can also set the ssh preferences per host but never did so. I you are interested into that, it might be worth looking.

Answer (score 1):

My answer: I just add a line to my ansible playbook. But it isn't an answer in terms of only Vagrant

```
- name: set locale
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/default/locale line="LC_ALL=C"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

**add these lines to ~/.bash_profile of VM, and restart VM via vagrant**

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Havok's answer, you can make the VM provisioning ensure that a locale (`en_US.UTF-8` below) is created, and used whenever you SSH into the VM (by running the necessary shell commands for configuring locales). In the `Vagrantfile`:

```rb
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-EOF
  apt-get update
  apt-get install -y locales  # install locales support
  echo 'en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8' >> /etc/locale.gen
  locale-gen  # enable locales in `/etc/locale.gen`
  update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8  # setup default VM locale
  sed -i -E 's/^(\s*AcceptEnv\b)/#\1/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config  # avoid SSH overriding it
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to configure the ssh daemon in the virtual machine to do not accept this environment variables.

Modify in your development environment the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and comment the `AcceptEnv` line like this:

```
$ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep AcceptEnv
# AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
```

If you're using Docker as provider you can put in your Dockerfile:

```
sed -i 's/AcceptEnv/# AcceptEnv/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

You need to generate and set the default locale too. You can do that with:

```
# Set the locale
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 && update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```